# I want to make scripts that will autolaunch autohotkey scripts and xpadder profiles and close on exit. How can I do this?

Tags: command, autohotkey, exit, launch

I have two separate key combinations required to exit emulators. Alt+F4 exits every emulator except the PS1 & PS2 emulators, which use 'Esc' as an exit command. I want to make scripts that will auto launch ahk scripts and xpadder profiles I have setup for these emulators and close said scripts and xpadder profiles on close of all of the emulators. How can I do this?

I created an account here for this specific purpose because I'm kind of at a last stand here and I have barely any experience programming. If this doesn't belong here then I wouldn't mind if a mod simply moved this to the desired location.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Have you read the [Asking FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? It's not the end of the world if you can't show any programming results. But if you don't provide enough information about the problem itself, no one will be able to help you. For starters, you can't presume that everyone knows what emulators are. I myself have no idea what xpadder is. What steps are neccessary to launch those profiles? What characteristics enable you to distinguish between them? Please provide more information!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly reccomend that you read the [AHK Documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs).

If you haven't already looked, there are plenty of places around the internet that introduce to to autohotkey. As a starter, I recommend [This Tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).

## IfWinActive may be of particular interest to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and it looks like AutoHotKey can handle what xpadder does.  One script can do window title detection and load up different hotkeys.  The actual tag is `#IfWinActive`

The advantage of `#IfWinActive` is you never have to turn off your AutoHotKey script.  I have one running that has over 100 different games of hotkeys setup.

Without knowing actual details, the script will look like this:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#IfWinActive PS1 Emulator ; actual title of the emulator.
; You can find out from Windows Spy that comes with AutoHotKey
1::
; does something special when 1 is pressed in PS1 Emulator
return

Joy1::
SendInput, A ; sends the "A" key when Joy1 button is pressed
return

#IfWinActive PS2 Emulator
1::
; does something special when 1 is pressed in PS2 Emulator
return
```

You also need to run this TEST script to figure out what your gamepad buttons register as under AutoHotKey
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/JoystickTest.htm